# if $\sqrt{a-1}+2\sqrt{b-4}+3\sqrt{c-9}+4\sqrt{d-16}+5\sqrt{e-25}=\frac{a+b+c+d+e}{2}$ then the value of $a+b+c+d+e$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

if  $\sqrt{a-1}+2\sqrt{b-4}+3\sqrt{c-9}+4\sqrt{d-16}+5\sqrt{e-25}=\frac{a+b+c+d+e}{2}$

then the value of $a+b+c+d+e$ ?

I have absolutely no idea on how to proceed. Please explain the solution in detail.

Comment: Why number theory? Are these variables integers?

Comment: i didn't know what else to tag this in?

Comment: Please explain the question in detail. And please add what you've tried/what you know might help/ etc, etc. (Also, please answer @Paola's question, and add that answer to your posted question.

Comment: @amWhy Paolo, please :P

Comment: @Paolo so sorry I misspelled!

Comment: intially i had no idea whatsoever, but thanks to all you guys, i now know how to solve this question. please remove your downvote, i am a new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider following two vectors 
$$\begin{cases}
u &= (1,2,3,4,5)\\
v &= (\sqrt{a-1},\sqrt{b-4},\sqrt{c-9},\sqrt{d-16},\sqrt{e-25})
\end{cases}$$
We have 
$$\begin{cases}
|u|^2 &= 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 = 55\\
|v|^2 &= a+b+c+d+e - 55
\end{cases}
\implies a+b+c+d+e = |u|^2 + |v|^2
$$
In terms of $u,v$, the given condition is equivalent to

$$u\cdot v = \frac{|u|^2 + |v^2|}{2} \quad\iff\quad
|u - v|^2 = 0\quad\iff\quad u = v$$
This implies $$a + b + c + d + e = |u|^2+|v|^2 = 2|v|^2 = 110$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
AM_GM gives
$$
2n\sqrt{a-n^2} \leq n^2 + (a-n^2)
$$
and equality holds iff
$$
a-n^2 = n^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $a=A^2+1,\ldots,e=E^2+25$, for some nonnegative integer $A,\ldots,E$ and set $M=\max\{A,\ldots,E\}$. Then
$$
A+2B+3C+4D+5E=\frac{1}{2}(A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2+E^2+55),
$$
i.e.
$$
2A+4B+6C+8D+10E=A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2+E^2+55.
$$
It follows that LHS is at most $30M$ and the RHS is at least $M^2+55$. But $M^2+55 \le 30M$ for just a few values.

Comment: thanks Paolo Leonetti for your answer. But I was able to get the answer 110 by following the hint given by iamvegan.

Comment: "The answer 55"? You'd notice my solution works only for integer-valued variables.

Comment: i have changed it to 110. i noticed my mistake just now.